# How to add JWT bearer correctly in this call Post javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day, i have this call and must add a field

```
var Invio=
    {
        "ad": "us",
        "ae": "pws"
    };
    
    var dati= JSON.stringify(Invio);
    $.post('endpointAPI',
    dati, 
 
    function(data, status) ////success callback
      {
        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      },
      
     
      'JSON' 
      );
```

how can i modify correctly the call
Thanks

Comment: Please tell us more. What field are you trying to add?. this feels like a you do it for me question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'YourRestEndPoint',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    data: YourData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log('succes: '+data);
    }
  });
```

you can make use of ajax call like this

Answer (score 0):

See the JQuery documentation here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

You can add parameters as an object, so you should do something like:

```js
$.post({   
  url: 'endpointAPI',
  data: dati,
  success: (success) => {...},
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
});
```

Comment: token is meant a variable that storage the string of bearer? $ retrieves the content of this string? @RobBailey

Comment: Correct. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: yeah, there's libraries out there which can help create/sign JWT